# Flow IDE support is fighting with Webpack

Tags: visual-studio-code, babeljs, atom-editor, webpack-dev-server, flowtype

I have flow integrated into a webpack / babel build using [flow-babel-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flow-babel-webpack-plugin) and it works great. Webpack dev server compiles / serves assets in less than a second and if there are flow type errors it prints them out nicely. I'm very happy with that.

The problem begins when I turn on my IDE. In both VSCode and Atom, if I enable any kind of flow support, my webpack / babel build immediately begins to choke. It will take anywhere between 4 and 70 seconds to compile any change. Often it fails and gives multiple `flow is still initializing` notices and indicates it has tried to start the server over and over.

I suspect that both webpack and the IDE are trying to spin up separate flow servers at the same time and this is causing a conflict. Or they are using the same flow server and this is, for some reason, also a problem. I just can't figure out what to do about it. I have tried pointing at separate binaries with webpack using the global `flow` and the IDE using the one from `node_modules`. No dice.

It seems like this must be an extremely common use case - flow + a webpack watcher + any IDE whatsoever.

I'd like to have both my webpack build compile flow code *and* have my IDE show me syntax errors etc. So far that's been impossible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that plugin uses its own copy of Flow, from the `flow-bin` package:

[index.js](https://github.com/zhirzh/flow-babel-webpack-plugin/blob/abb786b0b1b545c5c2715d807c338b4893f5051f/index.js#L2)

[package.json](https://github.com/zhirzh/flow-babel-webpack-plugin/blob/abb786b0b1b545c5c2715d807c338b4893f5051f/package.json#L8)

If this version is out of sync with what your IDE is starting up, then they will fight -- starting up one version of Flow will kill any Flow server with a different version that is already running in that directory.

If you put `flow-bin` in your `devDependencies` (alongside this webpack plugin) and lock it to a specific version, and also set your IDE to use the Flow binary from `flow-bin`, then it looks like `npm` will just install the version you specify, and both the plugin and the IDE will be able to use the same Flow version.

Without knowing more specifics about your setup, it's hard to recommend a more concrete solution. You'll have to either make it so both your IDE and this webpack plugin are running the same version of Flow, or stop using either the IDE or the webpack plugin.

Comment: It worked! Thank you! I want to add that I had to set `flow-bin` to the version used by the webpack plugin, since it was incompatible with the later version

Comment: That's weird, it looks like it should work with any version greater than `v0.33`. That's a pretty old version so things may not work as you expect. Nuclide, for example, is probably no longer fully compatible with that version. Not to mention the type checker improvements that have happened since then.

Comment: I expected it to work too, but it threw an error with a later version (0.44)